# How to generate and post .xlsx file to web api using Angular 2? Without downloading this file on local computer

Tags: angular, xlsx

On click on the upload button, I need to generate and post excel (.xlsx) file with a table to WEB API as FormData. The file shouldn't be downloaded on a local computer.

I am using Angular v10, If anyone has an idea please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a library to generate the xlsx files. Angular or browser doesn't have such functionality. The first one I found is [sheetjs](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs). Seems like a good one.

Answer (score 0):

To send data through WEB API, you need to convert `.xlsx` data into JSON, Once you create JSON you can send JSON data through HTTP service. You can create a table as well.

To convert `.xlsx` data into JSON look into the below jsFiddle example link.

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/xlsx-to-json)